# Ввод команд в командную строку

Tags: python

цель программы - в открытой командной строке, начать вводить команды по порядку:
'git init'
'heroku git:remote -a namebot'
'git add .'
'git commit -am "update"'
'git push heroku master'

после - закрытие командной строки

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю зачем тебе для этого питон.
Если сидишь под линуксом то:

```
alias deploy='git init && heroku git:remote -a namebot && git add && git commit -am "update" && git push heroku master'
```

Где deploy имя команды которая запускает то что идет после "="

Для виндовс смотри в сторону
doskey

Comment: P.S. 
Добавлять это надо в файл оболочки такие как .bashrc, .zshrc и тд